# Basic lemma in algebraic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I am going through the proof of a basic lemma from affine algebraic groups. Since I am not following it I would appreciate any clarification.

Lemma: Let $G$ is an algebraic groupIf $H$ in $G$ is an abstract subgroup, then $\overline{H}$ is a closed subgroup. 
Proof: Multiplication by $g$ is an isomorphism of varieties $G \rightarrow G$. Thus $g \bar{H} = \overline{gH}$ and $\overline{H} g = \overline{Hg}$. Therefore $\overline{H} \cdot \overline{H} \subset \overline{H}$. Similarly for inversion we have $(\overline{H})^{-1} = \overline{H}$.

1) First I am struggling with how to show $g \overline{H} = \overline{gH}$. 
I can see that $\overline{gH}  \subset g \overline{H} $ but how can I show the other direction?

2) How does $\overline{H} \cdot \overline{H} \subset \overline{H}$ follow?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: consider $g^{-1}$ for the first question. For the second, consider letting $g$ be in $\overline{H}$ in the previous statement.

Comment: Let $g,h\in \overline{H}$. Then $gh\in g\overline{H}=\overline{gH}\subset \overline{H}$.

Comment: I get both of them now. Thank you very much!